# Angular 4 If condition based on the value received from API

Tags: angular, primeng

I would like to change the background color of a primeng datatable based on the value from the API.

This is my array of part colors in object format that needs to match the party name being pulled from the API.

```typescript
this.partyColours = [{liberal: 'red'},{pc: 'blue'},{ndp: 'ndp'},{green: 'green'}];
```

This is my HTML code:

```html
<p-column field="politicalParty" header="Party" [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="equals" 
                                 [style]="background-color: {{partyColours}}">
  <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-col>
      <p-dropdown [options]="politicalParties" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" 
                  (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value,col.field,col.filterMatchMode)" 
                  styleClass="ui-column-filter"></p-dropdown>
  </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

As you can see that `"background-color: {{partyColours}}"` returns an error and I'm trying to figure out how to work the logic.

Comment: Yes, how do I do that?

Comment: As you can see from the example of that `[options]="politicalParties"` gets the parties from the API. If I can somehow connect the party name to the colours array it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

According to [the issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2157)

```
<ng-template let-col let-row="rowData" let-ri="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
   <span #x>{{ setColor(x, row[col.field]) }}{{row[col.field]}}</span>
</ng-template>


setColor(x, data) {
  x.parentNode.parentNode.style.background = this.partyColoursMap[data);
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/uFw4mVhWcl17pAhVOIaL?p=preview)**

**Old version:**

You can use the following syntax:

```html
<p-column field="politicalParty" header="Party" [filter]="true" class="red"
   [style]="{ backgroundColor: partyColoursMap[selectedParty] }" ...>
    <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-col>
      <p-dropdown [options]="politicalParties" [(ngModel)]="selectedParty" ...></p-dropdown>
    </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

where `partyColoursMap` object is calculated based on `partyColours` array:

```typescript
partyColoursMap: any = {};  

ngOnInit() {
  this.partyColours.forEach(x => 
      Object.keys(x).forEach(key => this.partyColoursMap[key] = x[key]));
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vub78f?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Thanks but your stackblitze example comes up empty in the its browser

Comment: Try to reopen it

Comment: Just did, no go

Comment: I added plunker

Comment: Thanks for the help but the question was regarding colouring individual cells according to their party

Answer (score 0):

```
<p-column field="politicalParty" header="Party" [filter]="true" filterMatchMode="equals" 
[style.backgroundColor]="pickColor(politicalParties.name)">
```

in your component

```
pickColor(name: string) {
if (name === 'liberal')
return 'red'
if( name === 'pc')
return 'blue'

// same structure for all parties
}
```

This is the simplest way, you can also go the class route. Obviously politicalParties.name needs to be correct...I don't know what your party object looks like, you might need to loop through an array or use *NgFor

Comment: Hey thanks, this is what my object looks like in the component:  `this.partyColours = [ { parties: [
      {liberal: 'red'},
      {pc: 'blue'},
      {ndp: 'ndp'},
      {green: 'green'}
    ]}]
      ;`

Comment: @azmatrix I meant the actual party info pulled from the API that you use to fill the component.